# Injecting dependencies

Tags: spring

The basic principle behind Dependency Injection (DI) is that objects define their dependencies (that is to say the other objects they work with) only through constructor arguments, arguments to a factory method, or properties which are set on the object instance after it has been constructed or returned from a factory method.

Here what exactly is this factory method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [last example in this Spring reference documentation section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-some-examples).

This is the sample:

```
<bean id="exampleBean" class="examples.ExampleBean" factory-method="createInstance">
    <constructor-arg ref="anotherExampleBean"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="yetAnotherBean"/>
    <constructor-arg value="1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="anotherExampleBean" class="examples.AnotherBean"/>
<bean id="yetAnotherBean" class="examples.YetAnotherBean"/>
```

ExampleBean class:

```
public class ExampleBean {

// a private constructor
private ExampleBean(...) {
    ...
}

// a static factory method; the arguments to this method can be
// considered the dependencies of the bean that is returned,
// regardless of how those arguments are actually used.
public static ExampleBean createInstance (
    AnotherBean anotherBean, YetAnotherBean yetAnotherBean, int i) {

    ExampleBean eb = new ExampleBean (...);
    // some other operations...
    return eb;
}
```

}

So, an instance of a bean is created using a factory-method inside the same bean. And the dependency injection is achieved by passing other beans as arguments to the factory-method.

Answer (score 0):

Factory Method is a design pattern for object creation. The Factory Method defines an interface for creating objects, but lets subclasses decide which classes to instantiate. For more information you can read [here](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method).